# How can I group a collection of elements by their adjacency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.5

Let's say I have a list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="q"></li>
    <li id="w"></li>
    <li id="e"></li>
    <li id="r"></li>
    <li id="t"></li>
    <li id="y"></li>
    <li id="u"></li>
    <li id="i"></li>
    <li id="o"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to do something like this:

```
function get_important_elements() {
    // completely contrived;
    // elements are guaranteed to be contained within same ul
    // but nothing else unique in common (class, attrs, etc)
    return $('#q, #w, #r, #u, #i, #o');
}

function group_adjacent($elems) {
    return $elems; //:(    
}

$(function () {
    var $filtered_list = get_important_elements();

    var groups = group_adjacent($filtered_list);

    // groups should be 
    // (shown by ID here, should contained actual elements contained
    // within jQuery objects): 
    // [$([q, w]), $([r]), $([u, i, o])]
});
```

How could I go about this?

Note that the IDs and classes used in the list are 100% contrived. In the real code upon which I'm basing this, I have a collection of `li` elements that are a subset of the `li`s contained in a single `ul`. This subset was determined by their contents, which are not important to the question at hand, not by class. They only share a class in the example for ease of getting my point across.

Comment: `[t]` should be `[r]`, `t` is `false`. Noticed after running my code.

Comment: So the real question is: given an array of elements, how to group them into adajcent elements.

Comment: Yep, keeping mind the elements that are not in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function group_adjacent($elems) {
    var rArr = [],
        currArr = $([]);
    $elems.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        currArr = currArr.add($this);
        if (!$elems.filter($this.next()).length) {
            rArr.push(currArr);
            currArr = $([]);
        }
    });
    return rArr;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adamjford/5q8fZ/3/

Comment: Sorry, the `true` class was a contrived part of the example. I've made the question a little more clear now, I hope.

Comment: I modified it to take that into account.

Comment: Suggest that you move the edit above the original, or better yet just leave the preferred, more generic answer.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, except I had to modify it as I needed an array of jQuery objects containing adjacent elements, not just their IDs. I've suggested an edit for the answer with my modifications.

Comment: I approved your edit, after adding a small change `$([])` to future proof it.

Comment: @KevinB: Is that overload being changed in 1.8?

Comment: It's more of a preventative measure just in case at some point `$()` selects the document instead of an empty document fragment. There was a version of jQuery where `$()` acted differently.

Answer (score 2):

Using plain script, you can get a collection of all the LIs and loop over it. If an element has the *true* class put it in a group array. If the next element has the class, put it in the same array. If it doesn't, start a new array. e.g.

```
function groupLis(){
    var el, els = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var group = [], groups = [group];

    for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      el = els[i];

      if (hasClass(el, 'true')) {

        if (!group) {
          group = [];
          groups.push(group);
        }
        group.push(el);

      } else if (group && group.length != 0) {
        group = null;
      }
    }
    return groups;
}

// Helper function
function hasClass(el, cName) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}
```

#### Edit

Ok, here is an answer for the revised question: given an array of elements, group them into arrays of adjacent siblings.

Note that it doesn't care if the elements are the same type, only that they are adjacent siblings (or not).

```
// el is a DOM node
// Returns the next element sibling, or undefined if here isn't one
function getNextSiblingElement(el) {
  while ((el = el.nextSibling)) {
    if (el.nodeType == 1) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}

// els is an array of DOM elements
// Returns an array of sibling element arrays
function groupEls2(els) {
  var el = els[0],
      group = [el],
      groups = [group];

  for (var i=1, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    el == getNextSiblingElement(els[i-1])? group.push(el) : groups.push((group = [el]));
  }
  return groups;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the `true` class was a contrived part of the example. I've made the question a little more clear now, I hope.

Comment: The edit makes it generic. The accepted jQuery answer is very inefficient, it will be slow for large arrays. I'd put up a test case but jsperf keeps crashing with IE 8.

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know. I haven't tested in browsers with slow JS engines like IE8 yet but I'll definitely keep this in mind if performance is an issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function group_adjacent($elems) {
    var temp = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var last = null;
    for(i = 0; i < $elems.length; i++) {
         if(last == $elems[i].previousSibling) {
             temp[i][j++] = $elems[i];
         }
         else {
             j = 0;
             temp[i] = new Array();
             temp[i][j++] = $elems[i];
         }
         last = $elems[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Oops. I neglected to mention something important in the question that is important to your answer.. Lemme fix that.

Comment: will nextSibling do it for you then?

Comment: Won't the first loop iteration throw an exception because you are accessing `last.nextSibling` and `last` is null?

Comment: almost certainly - changed to previousSibling